# Input an array from a form and post it to the server in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am working on a simple form that submits some data to the server. And there is a field where I have to add more than an input and store them in an array named "users". What I mean is, I want to have checkboxes and whenever I check a box, it adds its value to the array that is named users.  I am using this function to get values from the form and connect it to redux :

```
export function setFormValue(field) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch({ type: types.SET_FORM_VALUE, payload: field })
    };
}
```

Here is how my checkboxes are set in the form:

```
<FormGroup check>
                                    <Label check>
                                        <Input type="checkbox" onChange={setFormValue} value={form.users} />
                                    David
                                    </Label>
                                </FormGroup>
                                <FormGroup check>
                                    <Label check>
                                        <Input type="checkbox" onChange={setFormValue} value={form.users} />
                                    Marco
                                    </Label>
                                </FormGroup>
                                <FormGroup check>
                                    <Label check>
                                        <Input type="checkbox" onChange={setFormValue} value={form.users} />
                                    Leen
                                    </Label>
                                </FormGroup>
```

And here is how I am handling my form so that it will looks like :

```
form : {
     somedata : somedata,
     createAdress: {some data inside the object},
     users: []
}
```

And here is how I handle the state in the reducer :

```
import * as types from './actionTypes';

const initialState = {
    fetchedData: [
        {}
    ],
    branchWithID: {},
    form: {
        createAddress: {},
        users: []
    }
};

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                fetchedData: action.payload
            }
        case types.LOAD_BRANCH_WITH_ID_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                branchWithID: action.payload
            }
        case types.SET_FORM_VALUE:
            let form = action.payload
            form.users = form.users || [];
            const createAddress = [
                "nickname",
                "building_name",
                "office_number",
                "zone_number",
                "street_number",
                "building_number",
                "ciy",
                "area",
                "pin_link",
                "pin-lat",
                "pin-lng",
                "company",
                "customer"
            ];
            if (createAddress.includes(action.payload.target.name)) {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    form: {
                        ...state.form,
                        createAddress: {
                            ...state.form.createAddress,
                            [action.payload.target.name]: action.payload.target.value
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
            return {
                ...state,
                form: {
                    ...state.form,
                    [action.payload.target.name]: action.payload.target.value
                }
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

So now what I want is to take many inputs from the form and store them in the array of users. How can I achieve this?

Here is a link to my project on codesandbox :
https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-tree-eqb2n?file=/src/App.js

Comment: i m not sure i quite understood. you need e.g. to enter users with empy spaces and this should be stored as array in redux store `form.users` property?

Comment: @Apostolos I fixed it on Codesandbox. I want to have checkboxes and whenever I check a box, it adds its value to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so you need sth like the following

https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-goldberg-4wboi

First of all you can narrow your code by using `map` method.

```
    {["David", "Marco", "Leen"].map(name => {
      return (
        <FormGroup check>
          <Label check>
            <Input
              type="checkbox"
              name="users"
              value={name}
              onChange={setFormValue}
            />
            {name}
          </Label>
        </FormGroup>
      );
    })}
```

Second, you need to set the `name` property of the checkbox to be `users`, `value` property to be the name of each user, and finally you need to handle the `checked` property accordingly.

If `checked` then add user, else remove him from the list.

```
  if (action.payload.target.name === "users") {
    let clonedUsers = [...state.form.users];
    if (action.payload.target.checked) {
      clonedUsers.push(action.payload.target.value);
    } else {
      clonedUsers = clonedUsers.filter(
        user => user !== action.payload.target.value
      );
    }

    return {
      ...state,
      form: {
        ...state.form,
        users: clonedUsers
      }
    };
  }
```